# Why is my VARCHAR truncated to 255 characters? How do I fix this?

Tags: python, sql-server-2012, sqlalchemy, unixodbc

**Setup:**

I am using the following components:

- unixODBC 2.3.4
- FreeTDS 1.12
- Python 3.6
- SQLAlchemy

...against a MSSQL Server 2014.

**The problem:**

Suppose I have a table consisting of only 2 columns:

- id (primary key, int)
- my_text (VARCHAR())

My SQLAlchemy Model looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base import VARCHAR

MyText(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    my_text = Column(VARCHAR())
```

When I try to create a new text entry like so, and my text is longer than 255 characters, the string is silently truncated at 255.

```
my_text='REALLY LONG STRING THAT IS LONGER THAN 255. E.g.: 6000+ characters. Assume my string is 558 bp long.'
print(len(my_text))  # Gives 558 bp.
new_text = MyText(my_text=my_text)
print(len(new_text.my_text))  # Gives 558 bp.
db_s.add(new_text)
print(len(new_text.my_text))  # Gives 558 bp.
db_s.commit()
print(len(new_text.my_text))  # Gives 255 bp now after commit.
```

At first, I thought this is caused at write time to DB. But I found that this is caused at query time (read below).

**Question:**

*1.) Why is this happening?*

I think this has something to do with the drivers (e.g.: unixodbc 2.3.4, FreeTDS 1.12) but I am not entirely where exactly this is occurring.

*2.) More importantly, how do I fix this issue?*

These issues are related but different:

[MySQL VARCHAR index truncated to 255 during migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846239/mysql-varchar-index-truncated-to-255-during-migration)

The problem above is that I am not using MYSQL. So the solution provided does not fix the issue.

[unixODBC/FreeTDS results truncated to 255 character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18704593/unixodbc-freetds-results-truncated-to-255-character)

No solution is provided in that thread.

On that note, it should be noted that my strings can be routinely longer that 6000 characters (as I am working with long DNA sequences). I would really appreciate any way to fix the truncation issue.

**Update (2017-10-12):**

I made some remarkable but equally puzzling discoveries since yesterday.

```
# Connecting via pyodbc direct connection using just some helper functions to make things more convenient.
con_str = create_connection_string(DATABASE='test')
cur = make_connection_db(connection_str=con_str)
for row in cur.execute('SELECT Text.my_text, len(Text.my_text) FROM [test].[dbo].[Text]'):
    print(row)
    print(len(row[0]))
```

This gives me a string that is 558 characters long (see below).

```
 ('ATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATG', 
 558)
 558
```

Now using SQL Alchemy but still direct sql statements.

```
# Using SqlAlchemy connection with direct SQL query.
eoi_engine = create_engine(
"mssql+pyodbc://user:somepw@db:1234/test?driver=FreeTDS")
s_con = eoi_engine.connect()
s_res = s_con.execute('SELECT Text.my_text, len(Text.my_text) FROM [test].[dbo].[Text]')
for row in s_res:
    print(row)
    print(len(row[0])
```

This gives me a string that it claims is 558 characters long but in reality it is only 255 characters long.

```
 ('ATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATGATG', 
 558)
 255
```

And last scenario:

```
# Using SQLAlchemy full-stack.
Session = sessionmaker()

s = Session(bind=s_con)
fs_res = s.query(DNAPtsSeq).filter().all()
for row in fs_res:
    print(row)
    print(len(row.nt_seq))
```

This gives me a string that is only 255 characters long.

*So in summary:*

- The creation is caused not when WRITING things to the DB, but when querying things from the DB characters get silently truncated.
- I am only getting this problem of truncation when I use SQLAlchemy operations.

I don't know why I am only getting this error when I query using SQLAlchemy. Does anyone know the reason why? How can I fix this behavior? (I know the workaround is to use direct sql queries...)

Comment: Can you please add the return of `DESCRIBE table_name` (or the mssql equivalent) to this question?

Comment: If it is SQL Server, then try `varchar(max)` and also post result of `exec sp_columns <table_name>`

Comment: @Shadow: The table structure is really just as I noted above. Please, also see my comments above under the section "update". It's not saving to the db that is the issue, but when I query against that database in a certain way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my case, it turns out that there were several compounding errors, I am listing for posterity in case other people run into the same problem as I:

1. When I initially created the table, instead of declaring the table as VARCHAR(MAX), I declared them as VARCHAR(8000).
2. When I fixed the data table in the database, I did not change the ORM. The field was still VARCHAR(8000). Somehow this leads to a silent truncation.
3. Even changing VARCHAR(8000) to VARCHAR() did not fix the issue for me. It turns out that MSSQL VARCHAR(MAX) is highly non-standard. An obscure reference, led me to discover that there is a different VARCHAR just for MSSQL. If you import VARCHAR from the following location:

   ```
   from sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base import VARCHAR
   ```

...you can then declare your text field to be VARCHAR() which equals VARCHAR(Max) in MSSQL speak.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/mssql.html

This has increased the truncation limit to 4096 characters but not resolved it.

I tried to decipher the following answer here:

[SQLAlchemy Truncating VARCHAR(MAX)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844667/sqlalchemy-truncating-varcharmax)

Unfortuately, changing the text size buffer does not remove the truncation limit of 4096. In my case, I had to also precede queries to the DB with a sql statement from SQLAlchemy:

```
db_s.execute('Set TEXTSIZE {0}'.format(SOME_BIG_NUMBER_LIKE_20000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for old post

My solution was to use `CAST(FIELDNAME as NVARCHAR(4000))` in SELECT statement

If I use `CAST(FIELDNAME as NVARCHAR)`, SQLAlchemy will cut string

Comment: Do not include thanking in the posts. Please refer to [how-to-asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)